# On the Minkowski sum of unit cube with itself twice and three times, considered in dimensions two, three, and preferably beyond

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ be the unit cube $[0,1]^3$ without that part which lies in the ball of radius $1$ and center $(1,1,1)$. Is there a good description of the sets $A+A = \{\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}:\alpha_{k}\in A\}$ and $A+A+A$ (defined similarly). In $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ this problem is not so hard. First, let me draw $A$:

[image: Unit square without unit ball at (1,1)]

Now I can draw $A+A$ and $A+A+A$ just by geometric intuition:
[image: Twice and three times Minkowski sums]

We can describe both of these sets as a union of unit squares and some copies of $A$. I originally thought that in three dimensions that these sets would be similarly described: a union of unit cubes and some copies of $A$. I have been furiously trying to draw this and nothing looks right (because this description is almost surely wrong). I am thinking that maybe it can be described as a union of unit cubes, some of which have the unit ball removed (with center at some appropriate corner).

It would be extremely helpful to my life to have a good description of these sets, preferably one which extends to arbitrary dimension. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's past midnight here so I can't think straight, but why wouldn't you get a similar union of cubes and cubes with an octant of a ball removed? All the points within the cube with a single coordinate equal to zero are in $A$, no?

Comment: Jyrki, I think you are right. Just having a hard time visualizing it in my head. I am mostly interested in how many (not the shape) cubes and cubes with an octant removed it would be. For $A+A$ I think it would be $1$ cube and then $6$ shaved cubes. For $A+A+A$ I think it would be $7$ cubes and then $13$ shaved cubes? (I am not very confident about this one). I will try drawing more later tonight...

Comment: What's wrong with your proposed description of $A+A$ as a union of unit cubes and translations of $A$?  I find that there are unit cubes with (bottom-lower-left) corners $(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ and translations of $A$ at $(1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1)$.  Once this decomposition into cubes and translates of $A$ holds for $A+A$ and for $A + [0,1]^3$, it holds for $A+A+A$ and higher sums by induction.  Maybe I missed something though, so I'm interested to hear what you found to be the problem, and how confident you are that there is a problem.

Comment: Oh, as I posted that previous comment, the page refreshed and showed someone else had asked basically the same thing.

Comment: There are several tricks to see what's going on.  One is to note that all the faces of the unit cube with one coordinate zero are included in $A$.  By summing these faces, you can get all unit cubes with at most one coordinate greater than 1.  There are four such cubes in 3D.

Comment: It's trickier to show that certain unit cubes contain only a translation of $A$ and nothing more.  A minor trick I found useful was to consider Minkowski sums of $A':= [0,1]^3 - B_1(0)$, which is just rotated version of $A$.  I think I have an essentially complete proof that $A+A$ is just a union of cubes and translations of $A$, but I won't be able to write it up for a few hours.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you have a more precise write up. I imagine it will make easy $A+A+A$ easy to understand also, and probably work for higher dimensions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throughout this answer, when I speak of a unit cube or a translation of $A$ being "at" some point $(x,y,z)$, I will mean that the bottom-lower-left corner (0,0,0) is translated to that point.  The details of this answer are fairly involved at some points, and so I will skip some details when they amount to just checking many cases that are all qualitatively similar.

I find that $A+A$ consists of unit cubes at $(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ and translations of $A$ at $(1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1)$.  Similarly, I find that $[0,1]^3 + A$ consists of unit cubes at $(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1)$ and a translation of $A$ at $(1,1,1)$.  It will follow by induction that all higher sums of $A$, such as $A+A+A$, are also unions of unit cubes and translates of $A$.

Any point $(x,y,z)$ with at most one of $x,y,z$ in $(1,2]$, say $x\in (1,2]$ and $y,z \in [0,1]$, can be reached as a sum like $(1,y,0) + (x-1,0,z)$.  This shows that $A+A$ contains the unit cubes as claimed.  Similarly, for $[0,1]^3 + A$, as long as one of $x,y,z\in [0,2]$ is at most 1, say $z\leq 1$ and $x,y\in [1,2]$, we can write something like $(x,y,z) = (1,1,z) + (x-1,y-1,0) \in [0,1]^3 + A$.  So the unit cubes of $[0,1]^3 + A$ are as claimed.

Now, to show that there are translates of $A$ at the locations claimed requires two things: Showing that the Minkowski sum contains *at least* $A$ at that point is easy, e.g. to show that $A+A$ contains a translate of $A$ at $(1,1,0)$ follows immediately from the fact that $(1,1,0)\in A$, hence $(1,1,0)+A \subset A+A$.  However, to show that $A + A$ contains nothing more within the unit cube at $(1,1,0)$ is more difficult, and really is the only hard step in this entire proof.  Here goes:

We want to show that $A+A$ intersected with the unit cube at $(1,1,0)$ does not contain points within distance 1 of the top-upper-right corner $(2,2,1)$.  This means that $||(2,2,1) - x - y||\geq 1$ for any $x,y\in A$.  Equivalently, $||\left( (1,1,1) - x \right) + \left( (1,1,1) - y\right) - (0,0,1)|| \geq 1$.  Now by the definition of $A$, both $(1,1,1) - x$ and $(1,1,1) - y$ are vectors with all nonnegative components whose length is at least 1.  The extremal case is when both of these vectors lie on the unit sphere.  Let's suppose that this is the case, and call $u=(1,1,1)-x$ and $v=(1,1,1)-y$.  Then the preceding inequality can be written $||u+v-e_3||\geq 1$.  This is in turn equivalent to $||u - (e_3-v)||\geq 1$, which has the following nice geometric interpretation: $u$ lies on the positive octant of the unit sphere centered at the origin, and $e_3 - v$ lies on the negative octant of the unit sphere centered at $e_3$, so we are just asserting that the distance between the positive octant of the unit sphere centered at the origin and the negative octant of the unit sphere centered at $e_3$ is at least 1.
[image: Spheres]

In order for two points on the two spheres to be minimizers of distance, either they must be boundary points or the tangent planes at these two points must be perpendicular to the line connecting them, and in particular the tangent planes of the two points must be parallel to each other.  I'm not going to go through all the cases here, but basically the latter case of parallel tangent planes can't be a minimizer of distance, because points with equal tangent planes would need to be opposite points on the respective spheres, and because the two spheres are offset from each other, such points' tangent planes are not perpendicular to the line connecting them.  Similarly, when you work through all the boundary points, you find that the only possible minimizers are the vertices of the sphere octants, and checking all 9 cases you can see that the minimum distance is 1, as desired.

This proves the claim that $A+A$ is a union of cubes and translates of $A$.  A similar, easier argument shows that $[0,1]^3 + A$ has a translate of $A$ at $(1,1,1)$.

Now both $A+A$ and $[0,1]^3 + A$ consist of a union of cubes and translates of $A$, which are arranged on a lattice.  Inductively you can see that $A+A+A$ can be decomposed into a union of translates of $[0,1]^3 + A$ and $A+A$, and thus will itself consist of a union of cubes and translates of $A$.  To figure out where they all go is a combinatorial problem.  Adding $A$ to a cube at $(x,y,z)$ will result in cubes at $(x+1,y,z), (x,y+1,z),\dots$ and a translate of $A$ at $(x+1,y+1,z+1)$, and adding $A$ to a translate of $A$ at $(x,y,z)$ will result in cubes at $(x,y,z), (x+1,y,z), (x,y+1,z), (x,y,z+1)$ and translates of $A$ at $(x+1,y+1,z), (x+1,y,z+1),(x,y+1,z+1)$.  Working it all out, I find that $A+A+A$ will have translates of $A$ at $(2,2,0),(2,0,2),(0,2,2),(2,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,1,2)$ and cubes at $(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1),(1,1,1)(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2),(2,1,0),(2,0,1),(1,2,0),(0,2,1)$.

Analogous results should hold in all dimensions.  In general, $A+A$ will consist of translates of $A$ at all points of the form $(1,1,\dots,1) - e_k$ for some $k$, and cubes at all points of the form $(1,1,\dots,1) - e_{k_1} - e_{k_2} - \dots$, i.e. points with at least two 0 coordinates and the rest 1.  Then higher sums like $A+A+A$ will consist of translates of $A$ at points like $(2,2,\dots,2) - e_{k_1}-e_{k_2}$, of which there are $\binom{2+n-1}{2}$ (with $n$ being the dimension of the space), along with cubes at all points "below", i.e. subtracting more $e_k$'s.

Comment: Thank you for the work you have put into this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In 3d, I think the insight is that $A$ and therefore $A+A$, etc. are rotationally symmetric with respect to the line $x=y=z$. Therefore, if I'm not mistaken, one can discover the shape of $A+A$ by just looking at one cross-section—which is the 2d case. In other words, 3d $A+A$ should just be the 2d $A+A$ rotated around the line $y=x$. This shape, rather than a few cubes with balls removed, looks more like a single cube with a torus removed. Similar remarks should apply to $A+A+A$ (rotate the last 2d picture around $y=x$) and so on.

Comment: This is incorrect.  $A$ has symmetry only under rotations by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, not continuous rotational symmetry.

Comment: Greg, I believe this is the correct answer to a different question (which I am also interested in). For your answer to be true, A should be the unit cube with a certain torus removed. Thank you for alerting me to this idea.

Comment: @Yly: Damn, you're right.